# Make image inside child div take up 100% height based off of parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling to work this out and hope someone could offer some suggestions:

- I have a parent div which height is not specified so that it can be determined by its content.
- I then have two 'child' elements inside this parent div, but I only
  want one of these to determine the height of the parent div.
- The other child div contains an image and this image should take
  up 100% of its container (whose height should be based off of the
  height of the parent div) - this is done by specifying the value of height as: inherit.

Image to explain:
[image]

I have got everything to work as planned but once I add the image, it either doesn't fill up the full height of its container OR it causes the image to overflow which changes the height of the parent div (which I don't want to happen).

This is the code before the image is added:

```css
.parentDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.imageDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
}
.contentDiv {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.contentDiv p {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">

  <div class="imageDiv"></div>

  <div class="contentDiv">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is after the image is added:

```css
.parentDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.imageDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
}
.imageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imageContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  object-fit: cover;
}

.contentDiv {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.contentDiv p {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">

  <div class="imageDiv">
  
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <img src="http://www.unoosa.org/res/timeline/index_html/space-2.jpg">
    </div>
  
  </div>

  <div class="contentDiv">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I do know one way around this could be to set the image as a background-image but I don't want to do it like this and would like to know if it can be done in the way I've attempted above.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: It won't fint unless you set it as a background: cover

Comment: So it can't be done by using <img src=""> ? I am using the img alternative: object-fit: cover; which achieves the same thing

Comment: As I can see it will always proportionate on the height or the width so it basically won't fit the entire container. Moreover object-fit seems to be unsupported by IE and EDGE. Be careful :9

Comment: If you want it to fit, background is the way... Background not change the DOM elements, so you can easily shape your parent box. And with a little more technology you can achieve this even better.

Comment: @steo: ah okay, thanks. I will have to revise over the support again for object-fit

Comment: @Pimptech: okay that's a shame! I'll need to find a workaround for what I'm trying to do then! Thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
.parentDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.imageDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: orange;
  float:left;

}
.imageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imageContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  }

.contentDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.contentDiv p {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this frnt! Is there a way to do this while keeping flex box?

Comment: Welcome @bluguy. And regarding flex browser supports you can check that on caniuse.com, it doesn't support some old browsers. Surely there is a way to do this using flex too.